# Keyboard navigation for a year dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

By default, a dropdown that has a bunch of years in it has built in keyboard navigation. For instance, if I focus on the dropdown and type 1992, it will go to that option.

I am wondering if there is a way to enable a two digit year navigation, so that I can type 92, rather than the full 1992.

The other catch is that if you type a two digit year, then it would go to the most recent year in the dropdown. So if I type 09, then it would go to 2009 rather than 1909.

Anyone have any example or an idea on the best way to implement this with JQuery?

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/P2Xct/1/)

UPDATE:
It must work with Firefox 5 and IE7.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will get what you're looking for with just HTML + CSS. If you are using jQuery, I would definitely check out the Chosen plugin - http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/.

Comment: I updated my original post. JQuery can be used, but the chosen plugin doesn't seem to support IE7, which I need it to. Any other ideas?

Comment: You are right, it works in IE7. It doesn't seem to be working in Firefox 5 though.